# Missing Account Management Policies tab in WSO2 API Manager 2.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

On a stock and clean installation of the WSO2 API Manager 2.6, the **Account Management Policies** tab is missing from the *Carbon dashboard > Identity > Resident* page.

[image]

For this reason, also the forgot username/password/self-signup features in the OAuth2 service provider login are not working (405 Method not allowed).

Is there something to enable in the configuration files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For APIM version 2.6.0 and below you need to configure these using some configuration files. This is documented in [1].

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Identity+Management+for+the+API+Store

Comment: Configured and restarted but still when clicking on the "forgot password" link, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error, marking your answer as accepted because it actually reponds to the question.